# Will preventing default action of a hyperlink affect browser history?

Tags: javascript, browser, yui, browser-history

I have a hyperlink `<a href="another-link.html" id="anotherlink">another link</a>` and I prevent the default action of this hyperlink using YUI (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Event.html), that is on click I do not load the `another-link.html` in browser. Regardless of implementation, does this affect browser history?

Comment: Why not just try it and see? :)

Comment: @JohnP: Empiricism is great, but it's costly and error-prone. Best to back up one's empirical data with theory and specification (and, of course, vice-versa).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yup, I agree. I should have added 'And post your findings here' to that

Comment: Well, I was working on it, spent my time on it and then I decided to ask around. Hoped some one will point me to empirical analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not create that entry in the history as you didn't actually request it.